# A way to postpone the login screen/login field

Tags: login, lightdm

I'm looking for a way to postpone the login screen appearing upon boot, or a way to render the login field unusable either for a set amount of time or when a script finishes running (I need to wait for a specific line to appear in the syslog, or I can wait for 70 seconds). The method has to work on Ubuntu 16.04 with lightdm/Unity.

It must only postpone the login screen after booting up, not the 'lock screen'. If possible it should also be used when the computer wakes up from sleep, but this is not a requirement.

I've searching for a similar question but am only able to find questions related to reducing the login time and the likes, so pardon me if there's already a question like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Not sure why you would need to do this, but since it's been asked*

The `lightdm` display manager provides a number of 'hooks' into the process - although the documentation is, unfortunately, spotty. Probably the most useful one in this instance is the ability to specify a `greeter-setup-script` which is to be run when starting the greeter:

```
# greeter-setup-script = Script to run when starting a greeter (runs as root)
```

Using this, you could do the following:

1. Create an script somewhere e.g. `/usr/local/bin/greeter-setup-script` such as

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   /usr/bin/logger "starting greeter-setup-script"

   /bin/sleep 70

   /usr/bin/logger "stopping greeter-setup-script"
   ```

   The logger lines are just for verification - you can omit them if you wish; you could also replace the `sleep` command with something more sophisticated such as tailing and grepping the syslog. Make the script executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/greeter-setup-script
   ```
2. Create a custom configuration file in the lightdm configuration directory, such as `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/99-local-settings.conf`, containing the entry

   ```
   [SeatDefaults]
   greeter-setup-script = /usr/local/bin/greeter-setup-script
   ```

   If you already have a numbered customization file, or an `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file, you may add the entry to that.

When lightdm is restarted, the delay should be visible in /var/log/syslog, for example:

```
Aug 23 17:12:42 xenial-vm systemd[1]: Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
Aug 23 17:12:42 xenial-vm systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Aug 23 17:12:43 xenial-vm systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Aug 23 17:12:44 xenial-vm root: starting greeter-setup-script
Aug 23 17:13:54 xenial-vm root: stopping greeter-setup-script
Aug 23 17:13:54 xenial-vm systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of lightdm.
```

Comment: I'm experiencing some issues with Power Broker Identity Services. My domain goes 'offline' right after boot and only comes back online after a minute. As I'm unable to resolve this at the moment, I'd like to implement your answer as a workaround.